# Extract Data out of JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

This question has been asked a hundred times, but the internet isn't helping, mostly because I am new to swift and programming, so my apologies in advance.

I am trying to extract some data out json.

Here is my code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
request.httpMethod = "POST";

let postString = "email=\(email)";

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?
    do
    {

        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
        print(myJson)
        let name = myJson["name"]

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        err = error
    }
}
task.resume()
```

And here is the JSON out of `print(myJson)`:

```
(
    {
        name = "TestTest";
    }
)
```

But I am receiving an error for:

```
let name = myJson["name"]
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>       (lldb)

Comment: Your JSON top level object should be an array or dictionary and you need to serialize your object

Comment: As always but not related to the issue `mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift. And do not use `NSURL / NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3. There are native structs `URL / URLRequest`.

Comment: Okay thank you for your advice !

Comment: you just need to declare URLRequest using var instead of NSMutableURLRequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue you have is this line:

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
```

You specify that the data will be of type AnyObject. But it should really be an array of dictionaries. So, instead, you should specify:

```
let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as [[String:Any]]
```

Of course, that alone will not fix things since you have to extract items from the array before you can use dictionary notation to get at the "name" value. So, you'd have to do something like this, after that:

```
let row = myJson[0]
let name = row["name"]
```

Comment: @Fahim Thank you a lot for helping a beginner like me, that works !!! You are right I am doing a Post query, because this is a log in screen and while logging in I want to get the id(in this case the name) of the user to use it as a global variable. Im certain, that there is always one row, so can I do it without a for loop ?

Comment: @Jonas Happy to help :) And yes, you can extract just the first row then. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jonas Hope you have a great day as well :)